# Docker Django static files found but not working on HTML + ASGI path not found

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, django-channels

I am trying to deploy my app in django with docker but i am experiencing these 2 problems that are in the title.
I will explain better what I did.
Having problems starting ASGI with HTTP server I decided to split ASGI and WSGI into 2 different services, here is my docker-compose (WSGI I start with runserver to test):

```
version: '3'

services:
  web_asgi:
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=KeyOne.settings
      - DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE=true
    build: ./keyonecrm
    volumes:
      - ./keyonecrm:/code
    expose:
      - "8000"
    command: daphne -u /tmp/daphne.sock KeyOne.asgi:application
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

  web_wsgi:
    build: ./keyonecrm
    volumes:
      - ./KeyOneCRM:/code
      - ./KeyOneCRM/src:/code/src
    expose:
      - "8001"
    command: python ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./KeyOneCRM/src:/static
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - web_asgi
      - web_wsgi

  db:
    image: mongo:4.2.8
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0.7
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

Dockerfile for web and nginx:

```
FROM python:3.10

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install uvicorn

COPY . /code/

RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

---

```
FROM nginx:1.21-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        location /src/ {
            autoindex on;
            alias /static/;
        }
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://web_wsgi:8001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
        location /ws/ {
            proxy_pass http://web_asgi:8000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
    }
}
```

my settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import mimetypes

mimetypes.add_type("text/css", ".css", True)

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = '..'

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # "daphne",
    
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    
    'custom apps...',
    
    'channels',
    'phonenumber_field',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    # login middleware
    'apps.authentication.middleware.AuthMiddleware',
    'apps.authentication.middleware.PermissionMiddleware',
    
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'KeyOne.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'apps.notification.context_processors.notifications',
                'apps.monitoring.context_processors.page_info',
            ],
            'libraries': {
                'get_id': 'apps.utils.templatetags.custom_tags',
            },
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'KeyOne.wsgi.application'

ASGI_APPLICATION = "KeyOne.asgi.application"

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("127.0.0.1", 6379)],
        },
    },
}

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'keyone',
        'CLIENT': {
           'host': 'mongodb://db:27017/',
        }
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'it-IT'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Rome'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.User'

# static files
STATIC_URL = '/src/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'src')

# media files
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ["*"]
```

Ok now back to the problems, for the first one I was a bit shocked, on the web I only find problems regarding static files not being found while to me the problem is the opposite, static files are found but it is not applied in the HTML, I attach a picture so you can understand better:
[image]

As you can see neither styles nor js are completely ignored by HTML elements.
For the second problem, however, I can't connect to the websockets.
Here my asgi.py:

```
import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')
asgi = get_asgi_application()

from apps.communication.urls import websocket_urlpatterns
from apps.notification.urls import websocket_urlpatterns as n_wu
from apps.monitoring.urls import websocket_urlpatterns as m_wu

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # "http": asgi,
    "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(websocket_urlpatterns + n_wu + m_wu))
    ),
})
```

can anyone help me?